# Как сделать такую разметку?

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно сделать такую разметку?

[Разметка блоков http://i11.pixs.ru/storage/2/6/7/tabukatvla_4309482_18108267.jpg](http://i11.pixs.ru/storage/2/6/7/tabukatvla_4309482_18108267.jpg)

Не могу корректно сделать отступы.Правая колонка съезжает вниз (возможно не правильно поставленные флоат).

Прошу объяснить хотя-бы вкратце как правильно сделать?

Comment: А в чем сложность?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Скорее всего, суммарная ширина трёх колонок превышает ширину контейнера, в котором они лежат.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите ваш вариант html+css
Вкратце - сумма ширин всех колонок и отступов должны быть меньше или равняться ширине общего контейнера

Comment: Да,с шириной вы были правы,подредактировал блоки и теперь они умещаются.Вопрос теперь в следующем,каким правильным вариантом будет расположить блоки друг под другом(те малые блоки),я так понимаю их нужно засунуть в отдельный div и задать ширину,но правильно ли это будет?

Comment: да, вполе правильно